# How do I display information in a table format using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I'm currently writing a very simple JavaFX application which will hopefully display information from a database. Getting the information has been simple enough but I want to display it in a table which the user can scroll through and make a selection from. Initially looking through the JavaFX controls in Netbeans I thought the best control to use was the List View. However looking through the examples of its use I'm unable to find any where this control displays information in a tabular style.

Can anyone tell me if the List View control can be used in this way ? and if so can you point to any simple examples.

Thanks for your time.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX currently (v1.3) does not have table controls. Try [jfxtra.org](http://jfxtras.org/portal/samples).